# Adding ASP.NET User Controls at runtime via <script runat="server">

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, user-controls, asp.net-controls

I am having trouble executing a control inside the `<script runat="server">` tags in an `*.aspx` page.

The control works when it is defined declaratively in the HTML section of the page, but I am unable to make it work when placed within the script tag itself.

At the beginning of the page I register my control with:

```
<%@ Register assembly="App_Web_exemple.ascx.cc671b29" namespace="Moncontrol" tagprefix="moncontrol" %>
```

Then, in the HTML, I call it (successfully) with the following declaration:

```
<moncontrol:exemple ISBN="9782894646151" runat="server" />
```

When I try to add it programmatically within the `<script runat="server">`, however, I am unable to execute it. I tried with the tags `<asp:Text />` and  `<asp:Literal />`, as follows, but that also doesn't doesn’t work.

In the HTML part:

```
<asp:Text id="TestControl" runat="server" />
```

In the script part

```cs
TestControl.Text = "<moncontrol:exemple ISBN=\"9782894646151\" runat=\"server\" />";
```

Comment: I see a lot of downvotes for this question. If you have concerns about the wording, consider adding a comment so the author can revise the post. A downvote without feedback isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, what you're looking to do is programmatically add a User Control to your Web Forms page at runtime. There are a few ways of accomplishing this.

> Before we begin, it's worth noting that the code you wrote likely "works" insomuch that it compiles and doesn't throw a runtime error. But it's also not executing the control. I suspect if you look at your HTML, you'll find the control declaration being output as a string literal (i.e., unprocessed by the server). It is then disregarded by the browser since it doesn't know what the `<moncontrol:exemple />` tag represents. That's obviously not what you want.

### Establishing a Control Container

Regardless of which approach you take, you'll want to start with some type of container on your page that you can add the control to, such as a `Panel`. If you don't want the container to output any wrapper markup, you can use a `Placeholder`:

```
<asp:Placeholder id="ControlContainer" runat="server" />
```

This serves a similar purpose as your current `Text` control, except its *only* purpose is to provide a container that you will add your user control to. From ASP.NET's perspective, however, this can be *any* type of server control, including a `<script runat="server">`, as per your request. More on that later.

### Programmatically Creating the Control

Next, you're going to create the control programmatically. This is where we run into various options. The most universal approach is to use `ParseControl()` method ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz3ffe28%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). This looks something like this:

```cs
Control control = Page.ParseControl("<%@ Register assembly=\"App_Web_exemple.ascx.cc671b29\" namespace=\"Moncontrol\" tagprefix=\"moncontrol\" %><moncontrol:exemple ISBN=\"9782894646151\" runat=\"server\" />");
```

That will parse the control using the same method that processes the declarative syntax on the page, and return a `Control` object with your `Exemple` control as the first control in its `Controls` collection.

I find that syntax a bit sloppy, however, since it's representing a .NET object and its properties as a string literal. Given that, there are some cleaner approaches. In this case, it appears that your control is being compiled into an assembly and, therefore, likely has a Code Behind defined which inherits from `UserControl`. If so, you should be able to simply do something like:

```cs
Exemple control = new Exemple();
```

And then set the properties on it programmatically, the way you would in any other C# object. Much cleaner!

> If your control was instead being compiled dynamically by the server, then you'd instead use the `Reference` directive with the `LoadControl()` method, as described in the MSDN article [How to: Create Instances of ASP.NET User Controls Programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0az2h86%28v=vs.140%29.aspx). I don't believe that method will work for you, however.

### Adding the Control Instance to the Page

Regardless of which approach you take, the next step is the same: you then add the control you've programmatically added to your page by adding it to the `Controls` collection of the target container. E.g.,:

```cs
ControlContainer.Controls.Add(control);
```

> *Note*: You can technically just add this to the `Page` class's `Control` collection, too, but that doesn't give you any control over *where* on the page it is placed; having a `PlaceHolder` control (or equivalent) lets you specify *exactly* where you want the control to appear.

I hope this helps. There are a couple of caveats depending on how you wrote and compiled your control, but this should give you the basic structure needed to address your problem.

Comment: No problem, @Ulysse. Did this resolve your issue? It's a fun challenge, and once you have this concept locked down there are a lot of really cool things you can do such as dynamically adding and configuring controls to a page (e.g., in response to configuration in a database).